# Unable to use query.ToObservable(), cannot find reference dll

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate to create WPF app(.net 4.0) and I was going through the tutorial from pluralsight for .NET Reactive Extensions Fundamentals

_http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/reactive-extensions

An example of an WPF is shown where a simple button and readonly textbox is used when the button is clicked the text of textbox is appended with the numbers generated using Enumerable linq query. The application keeps responding without being dead because asynchronous task is performed.

The application adds reference of System.CoreEx, System.Observable and System.Reactive

and suppose a line of code is like

```
var query = from number in Enumerable.Range(1, 25) select number;

var observableQuery = query.ToObservable() // ToObservable() is not seen in intellisense
```

because I am unable to find and add reference.

I tried to search on google and also installed

Reactive Extensions from

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=26649

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610

but I was unable to find all dll files. I found System.Reactive in my system in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Reactive Extensions SDK\v1.0.10621\Binaries.NETFramework\v4.0

and while searching on google I read somewhere that System.CoreEx is now included in System.Reactive so its not required the remaining is System.Observable which I am unable to find.

So where can I find that dll or what do I need to install to get that dll. I even tried through nuget but unable to find.

If anybody could suggest where can get the System.Observable dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to changes in versions I had to face issues but finally with help and guidance of @Lee I could resolve it. Thanks @Lee. I would like to bring here entire stuff so that it is helpful maybe to some other.

Here is the xaml part:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="Start" Click="Start_Click">Start</Button>
    <TextBox Name="Results" Height="250" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the .cs file coding:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static string StringWait(string str)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        return str;
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = from number in Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000)
                    select StringWait(number.ToString());
        var observableQuery = query.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default);
        observableQuery.ObserveOn(Dispatcher).Subscribe(n => Results.AppendText
            (string.Format("{0}\n",n)));

    }
  }
}
```

And finally here are the references I need to have:

http://i49.tinypic.com/vp7sk7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Download Silverlight Toolkit [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30514): Then add reference to System.Reactive.dll (by default - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\Oct09\Bin)

Comment: Thanks Cris for reply but as I mentioned above if you could please refer it again I already got System.Reactive.dll in my system in 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Reactive Extensions SDK\v1.0.10621\Binaries.NETFramework\v4.0 

What I am unable to find is System.Observable dll

Comment: you are using v1.0.10621,try using v2.0 for reactive extensions

Answer (score 0):

The `ToObservable` extension method is defined in the `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable` class, which is found in `System.Reactive.Linq.dll`. Therefore, you need to add a reference to the System.Reactive.Linq assembly, and in your source file add a

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```

directive.

EDIT: In response to your comment, it appears you want to do the following:

```
IObservable<string> observableQuery = query.ToObservable();
observableQuery.subscribe(Results.AppendText);
```

[TextBoxBase.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) is convertible to an `Action<string>`, and there is an extension method defined in [ObservableExtension.Subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402849.aspx) which allows an `Action<string>` to subscribe to an `IObservable<T>`'s `OnNext` method.

To use this you need to add a reference to `System.Reactive.Core.dll` and add a

```
using System;
```

directive in your source file.

Comment: Thanks for reply but while trying that I got error. Here is the screenshot 

http://i48.tinypic.com/1ys7a.jpg

Comment: @user1673411 - Are you referencing multiple different versions of the assembly? Make sure you only have one reference to `System.Reactive.Linq.dll`. You might also want to clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Ok I found and removed System.Reactive.dll reference from solution which has removed the error. But then using System.Reactive.Linq.dll and later adding using System.Reactive.Linq; ofcourse allows to use query.ToObservable() but maybe this is not the piece required in my example, reason is the next line of code gives error because using these references give different meaning to it just check the screenshot from 
http://i46.tinypic.com/jsy81v.png
in coding 'Results' is name of textbox and just by this code 1 to 25 number is printed successfully in tutorial but I unable to run due to error

Comment: @user1673411 - I've updated the answer, which should solve your problem. You need to add a reference to `System.Reactive.Core.dll` and add a `using System;` directive to your source file(s).

Comment: Great work! Thanks for guidance it helped a lot to clear the issue. I had to add one more reference after adding System.Reactive.Core.dll which was clearly mentioned in error that I added and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest .net framework, simply try installing this [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) nuget package, and you should be up and running.